# What could be the result of this missing o-ring?

Tags: carburetor, acceleration

Consider this o-ring :

[image]

And [this full diagram](http://www.cheapcycleparts.com/oemparts/a/kaw/500b23f8f8700223e478cb03/carburetor-2-3) if you need a more global view :

[image]

---

For completeness sake, here are the real parts :

**Where the o-ring goes :**[image]

**Where the little hole leads :**
[image]

**The other end of the path is at the top of the venturi :**
[image]

**Another hole :**
[image]

**Which leads there :**
[image]

**Little hole in caps where o-ring goes :**
[image]

**And for completeness, what goes inside :**
[image]

**Both-side view of the diaphragm :**
[image]

---

What could be the result of this missing o-ring ?

My hypothesis is that a bad acceleration would occurs since air flow would be corrupted.

Am-I right and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you could very well be correct. The passage you are pointing out with the missing is an air passage which acts as a *pressure reference*. The diaphragm (last picture) is actually the accelerator pump. As the butterfly opens, more air is sucked in, causing a high pressure point at the top of the venturi (picture marked as: **The other end of the path from the inside** ). This forces the air through the hole and tube and behind the diaphragm which pumps fuel into the incoming air. This gives a larger boost of fuel, which allows richens the air up a bit until the carb venturi fuel inlet can catch up.

With the o-ring gone, there is no air reference (or very little) going on. The diaphragm cannot pump the extra fuel which the engine needs. When this o-ring is back in place, I would surmise you'll see a great increase in how the bike accelerates, as long as the rest of the carb is put back together correctly. The o-ring looks like you could replace it from pretty much any o-ring kit (it doesn't look like it's anything special).

Comment: This is exactly the explanation I had in my head, expect that in my head the real names were replaced with "little holes" etc ;) .. I'll edit my question with the real names when I come back from work and follow up on this. No problem to get back correctly the rest of the carb together.

Comment: Believe it or not, I gained 30km/h top speed and and insanely faster acceleration. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard - The acceleration doesn't surprise me, but the top speed does! Good deal :D

Comment: To explain more about the top speed, I was not able to go over 5 rpm without that o-ring. It definitely worth the 4$ CAD even tho that seems a lot for a such little piece.

Comment: $4 CAD = 30km/h ... I'd say it's *well worth it* ... If someone out on the Bonneville Salt Flats could get 30km/h more out of their vehicle for that price, they'd be *all over it*. Good deal.